# How to sum multiple rows with specific criteria in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query to sum balances by Product below:

```
SELECT BCM_CORPORATION_NUMBER, BCM_PRODUCT
  SUM(BCM_TOT_NEW_BAL) AS TOTAL_BALANCE
FROM BCM_IN
GROUP BY BCM_CORPORATION_NUMBER, BCM_PRODUCT
ORDER BY BCM_CORPORATION_NUMBER ASC;
```

**Results**:

```
Corp.        PRODUCT.    TOTAL_BALANCE
002030.      VCLBUS.       3000
002030.      VGOBUS.       1000
002030.      VCL000.       4000
```

I want to combine the totals for Products VCLBUS & VGOBUS to display a total of 4000 together without the VCL000 product.

To look like this:
Corp.             PRODUCT.                TOTAL_BALANCE
    002030.      VCLBUS/VGOBUS.       4000
    002030.      VCL000.                        4000

Comment: where to display the vclbus + vgobus? in separate column?

Comment: Yes that would be great

Comment: please show the expected result that you want

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT BCM_CORPORATION_NUMBER, SUM(BCM_TOT_NEW_BAL) AS TOTAL_BALANCE
FROM BCM_IN
WHERE BCM_PRODUCT IN ('VCLBUS', 'VGOBUS')
GROUP BY BCM_CORPORATION_NUMBER
ORDER BY BCM_CORPORATION_NUMBER ASC;
```

Or you may what:

```
WHERE BCM_PRODUCT <> 'VCL000'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's your query.

```
SELECT t1.BCM_CORPORATION_NUMBER, t1.BCM_PRODUCT, SUM(t1.TOTAL_BALANCE) 
FROM (SELECT BCM_CORPORATION_NUMBER, BCM_PRODUCT
     SUM(BCM_TOT_NEW_BAL) AS TOTAL_BALANCE, 
     FROM BCM_IN
     GROUP BY BCM_CORPORATION_NUMBER, BCM_PRODUCT
     ) t1
WHERE t1.BCM_PRODUCT IN ('VCLBUS', 'VGOBUS')
ORDER BY t1.BCM_CORPORATION_NUMBER ASC
```

**or**

```
SELECT BCM_CORPORATION_NUMBER
    , BCM_PRODUCT
    , BCM_TOT_NEW_BAL
    , SUM(BCM_TOT_NEW_BAL) AS TOTAL_BALANCE
FROM BCM_IN
WHERE BCM_PRODUCT IN ('VCLBUS', 'VGOBUS')
GROUP BY BCM_CORPORATION_NUMBER, BCM_PRODUCT, BCM_TOT_NEW_BAL
ORDER BY BCM_CORPORATION_NUMBER ASC;
```

Comment: So you did a Self Join on table query? I'm assuming WHERE T.1 BCM_PRODUCT IN ('VCLBUS', 'VGOBUS')

Comment: In the second query how can I combine the total balance as a separate column?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your `Output` is in Temp table or `CTE`

```
create table #Output(Corp varchar(15),PRODUCT varchar(50),TOTAL_BALANCE int)



insert into #Output 
SELECT BCM_CORPORATION_NUMBER, BCM_PRODUCT
  SUM(BCM_TOT_NEW_BAL) AS TOTAL_BALANCE
FROM BCM_IN
GROUP BY BCM_CORPORATION_NUMBER, BCM_PRODUCT
;
```

OR

```
;With OutPutCTE
(
SELECT BCM_CORPORATION_NUMBER, BCM_PRODUCT
  SUM(BCM_TOT_NEW_BAL) AS TOTAL_BALANCE
FROM BCM_IN
GROUP BY BCM_CORPORATION_NUMBER, BCM_PRODUCT
--ORDER BY BCM_CORPORATION_NUMBER ASC
)
```

Suppose, like you want to group `'VCLBUS', 'VGOBUS'` 
Similarly you will want to Sum `GROUP` other Product  and `SUM` them accordingly.

Create #temp table and store product according to their group

```
create table #GroupType(PRODUCT varchar(50),groupid int)
insert into #GroupType values
 ('VCLBUS.',1)
,('VGOBUS.',1)
,('VCL000.',2)

select o.* 
,sum(TOTAL_BALANCE)over(partition by g.groupid )Group_TOTAL_BALANCE 
from #Output O
inner join #GroupType G on o.PRODUCT=g.PRODUCT
```

I think you can get the whatever output you want.